# Curl gives response but python does not and the request call does not terminate?

Tags: python-3.x, curl, web-scraping, urllib3

I am trying this following curl request

```
curl 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/historical/cm/equity?symbol=COALINDIA&series=\[%22EQ%22\]&from=03-05-2020&to=03-05-2021&csv=true' \
-H 'authority: www.nseindia.com' \
-H 'accept: */*' \
-H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36' \
-H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' \
-H 'sec-gpc: 1' \
-H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
-H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
-H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
-H 'referer: https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol=COALINDIA' \
-H 'accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' \
-H 'cookie: ak_bmsc=2D5CCD6F330B77016DD02ADFD8BADB8A58DDD69E733C0000451A9060B2DF0E5C~pllIy1yQvFABwPqSfaqwV4quP8uVOfZBlZe9dhyP7+7vCW/YfXy32hQoUm4wxCSxUjj8K67PiZM+8wE7cp0WV5i3oFyw7HRmcg22nLtNY4Wb4xn0qLv0kcirhiGKsq4IO94j8oYTZIzN227I73UKWQBrCSiGOka/toHASjz/R10sX3nxqvmMSBlWvuuHkgKOzrkdvHP1YoLPMw3Cn6OyE/Z2G3oc+mg+DXe8eX1j8b9Hc=; nseQuoteSymbols=[{"symbol":"COALINDIA","identifier":null,"type":"equity"}]; nsit=X5ZCfROTTuLVwZzLBn7OOtf0; AKA_A2=A; bm_mi=6CE0B82205ACE5A1F72250ACDDFF563E~LZ4/HQ257rSMBPCrxy0uSDvrSxj4hHpLQqc8R5JZOzUZYo1OqZg5Q/GOt88XNtMbsWM8bB22vtCXzvksGwPcC/bH2nPFEZr0ci6spQ4GOpCa/TM7soc02HVf0tyDTkmg/ZdLZlWzond4r0vn+QpSB7f3fiVza1Gdx9OaFL1i3rvqe1OKmFONreHEue20PL0hlREVWeLcFM/5DxKArPwzCSopPp62Eea1510iivl7GmY=; nseappid=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJhcGkubnNlIiwiYXVkIjoiYXBpLm5zZSIsImlhdCI6MTYyMDA2MTQ5OSwiZXhwIjoxNjIwMDY1MDk5fQ.YBTQ0MqRayD3QBM3V6zUt5zbRRICkbIhWWNedkDYrdU; bm_sv=C49B743B48F174C77F3DDAD188AA6D87~bm5TD36snlaRLx9M5CS+FOUicUcbVV3OIKjZU2WLwd1PtHYUum7hnBfYeUCDv+5Xdb9ADklnmm1cwZGJJbiBstcA6c5vju53C7aTFBorl8SJZjBN/4ku61oz0ncrQYCaSxkFGkRRY9VMWm6SpQwHXfMsUzc/Qk7301zs7KZuGCY=' \
--compressed
```

This gives us the required response (example below)

```
"Date ","series ","OPEN ","HIGH ","LOW ","PREV. CLOSE ","ltp ","close ","vwap ","52W H","52W L ","VOLUME ","VALUE ","No of trades "
"03-May-2021","EQ","133.00","133.45","131.20","133.05","132.20","132.20","132.21","163.00","109.55",10262391,"1,356,811,541.80",59409
```

But if I use the following python script to get the data

```
import requests

headers = {
'authority': 'www.nseindia.com',
'accept': '*/*',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36',
'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
'sec-gpc': '1',
'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
'referer': 'https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol=COALINDIA',
'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8','cookie':'ak_bmsc=2D5CCD6F330B77016DD02ADFD8BADB8A58DDD69E733C0000451A9060B2DF0E5C~pllIy1yQvFABwPqSfaqwV4quP8uVOfZBlZe9dhyP7+7vCW/YfXy32hQoUm4wxCSxUjj8K67PiZM+8wE7cp0WV5i3oFyw7HRmcg22nLtNY4Wb4xn0qLv0kcirhiGKsq4IO94j8oYTZIzN227I73UKWQBrCSiGOka/toHASjz/R10sX3nxqvmMSBlWvuuHkgKOzrkdvHP1YoLPMw3Cn6OyE/Z2G3oc+mg+DXe8eX1j8b9Hc=; nseQuoteSymbols=[{"symbol":"COALINDIA","identifier":null,"type":"equity"}]; nsit=X5ZCfROTTuLVwZzLBn7OOtf0; AKA_A2=A; bm_mi=6CE0B82205ACE5A1F72250ACDDFF563E~LZ4/HQ257rSMBPCrxy0uSDvrSxj4hHpLQqc8R5JZOzUZYo1OqZg5Q/GOt88XNtMbsWM8bB22vtCXzvksGwPcC/bH2nPFEZr0ci6spQ4GOpCa/TM7soc02HVf0tyDTkmg/ZdLZlWzond4r0vn+QpSB7f3fiVza1Gdx9OaFL1i3rvqe1OKmFONreHEue20PL0hlREVWeLcFM/5DxKArPwzCSopPp62Eea1510iivl7GmY=; nseappid=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJhcGkubnNlIiwiYXVkIjoiYXBpLm5zZSIsImlhdCI6MTYyMDA2MTQ5OSwiZXhwIjoxNjIwMDY1MDk5fQ.YBTQ0MqRayD3QBM3V6zUt5zbRRICkbIhWWNedkDYrdU; bm_sv=C49B743B48F174C77F3DDAD188AA6D87~bm5TD36snlaRLx9M5CS+FOUicUcbVV3OIKjZU2WLwd1PtHYUum7hnBfYeUCDv+5Xdb9ADklnmm1cwZGJJbiBstcA6c5vju53C7aTFBorl8SJZjBN/4ku61oz0ncrQYCaSxkFGkRRY9VMWm6SpQwHXfMsUzc/Qk7301zs7KZuGCY=',}

params = (
('symbol', 'COALINDIA'),
('series', '/["EQ"/]'),
('from', '30-04-2021'),
('to', '03-05-2021'),
('csv', 'true'),
)

response = requests.get('https://www.nseindia.com/api/historical/cm/equity', headers=headers, params=params)
```

It gets stuck in the last line.

I am using python3.9 and urllib3.

Not sure what is the problem.
This url downloads a csv file from the website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to jump through some loops with Python to get the file you're after. Mainly, you need to get the request header `cookie` part right, otherwise you'll keep getting `401` code.

First, you need to get the *regular* cookies from the authority `www.nseindia.com`. Then, you need to get the `bm_sv` cookie from the `https://www.nseindia.com/json/quotes/equity-historical.json`. Finally, add something that's called `nseQuoteSymbols`.

Glue all that together and make the request to get the file.

Here's how:

```python
from urllib.parse import urlencode

import requests

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '
                  'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'referer': 'https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol=COALINDIA',
}

payload = {
    "symbol": "COALINDIA",
    "series": '["EQ"]',
    "from": "04-04-2021",
    "to": "04-05-2021",
    "csv": "true",
}

api_endpoint = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/historical/cm/equity?"

nseQuoteSymbols = 'nseQuoteSymbols=[{"symbol":"COALINDIA","identifier":null,"type":"equity"}]; '


def make_cookies(cookie_dict: dict) -> str:
    return "; ".join(f"{k}={v}" for k, v in cookie_dict.items())


with requests.Session() as connection:
    authority = connection.get("https://www.nseindia.com", headers=headers)
    historical_json = connection.get("https://www.nseindia.com/json/quotes/equity-historical.json", headers=headers)
    bm_sv_string = make_cookies(historical_json.cookies.get_dict())

    cookies = make_cookies(authority.cookies.get_dict()) + nseQuoteSymbols + bm_sv_string
    connection.headers.update({**headers, **{"cookie": cookies}})

    the_real_slim_shady = connection.get(f"{api_endpoint}{urlencode(payload)}")
    csv_file = the_real_slim_shady.headers["Content-disposition"].split("=")[-1]
    with open(csv_file, "wb") as f:
        f.write(the_real_slim_shady.content)
```

Output -> a `.csv` file that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I know this may not be in the scope of the question but how did you find out this is what needs to be done ? As in with other websites, the way I have done in my question was working fine . I would not be using requests.session() and the steps you have suggested.

Comment: Well, all I did was *faking* the request to resemble the one that was sent by a browser. If you look at Network -> XHR tab in the Developer's Tools you'll see that the cookie needs to go with the request header. `request.Session()` helps to reuse that data, as you can see in my answer.

Comment: Nice explanation +

Comment: @QHarr, appreciate it.